# como utilizar un string para usar los numero ya ingresados en otra operación en dev-c++?

Tags: dev-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,i,va;
float num,t,p;
cout<<"cuantos numero desa ingresar?"<<endl;
cin>>n;
i=1;

while (i<n+1){
    cout<<"dame el valor del numero: "<<i<<":";
    cin>>num;
    t=t+num;

    i++;
}

cout<<endl<<"el promedio es: "<<t/n<<endl;
cin>>t;


cout<<endl<<"el valor absoluto de cada numero es: "<<t-num<<endl;//quiero usar los numero ya ingresados para hacer esta operación
cin>>va;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Según entiendo, lo que quieres es utilizar esos mismo datos que obtuviste en otras funciones dentro del mismo archivo?

Comment: Si quieres hacer eso, tan solo declaralas de manera Global.

Comment: ya lo intente pero no me da el resultado correcto, usa el ultimo numero que tiene la variable guardada en ves de hacerlo desde el primer dato ingresado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entendí, lo que quieres hacer es reutilizar los valores uno por uno, ¿cierto?

Necesitas almacenar cada uno de esos valores, ya sea en un arreglo, o en un vector.

Y luego trabajas con ellos uno por uno.

Pedimos la cantidad de números que le usuario ingresará.

```
vector<float> vtNums; //Acá almacenaremos cada entrada del usuario.
int nCant; //La cantidad de números que el usuario quiere ingresar.
float value = 0, total = 0; //Value -> Cada entrada del usuario; total -> La suma de todas esas entradas.

cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter?" << endl;
cin >> nCant;
```

Almacenamos cada uno de ellos en un vector y al mismo tiempo vamos llevando la cuenta del total.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < nCant; counter++) {
    cout << "Enter the value for the '" << counter + 1 << "' number: ";
    cin >> value;

    vtNums.push_back(value);
    total += value;
}
```

Y por último mostramos los resultados que queremos.

```
cout << "The average value from those inputs is: " << total/nCant << endl;

for(int counter = 0; counter < nCant; counter++) {
    cout << "The absolute value for " << vtNums.at(counter) << " is: " << abs(vtNums.at(counter)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: hola RottenChese creo que esta correcto tu comentario solo no comprendo, tengo que crear un vector? o una string?

Comment: Si quieres trabajar con los valores numéricamente uno por uno, lo mejor sería una estructura que te permita almacenarlos de tal forma que luego puedas trabajar con ellos directamente. En este ejemplo, utilicé un vector. Podrías usar una cadena (string) también, pero tendrías que trabajar con conversiones. De esta forma te saltarías esa parte.

Comment: ya lo eh intentado y al parecer me marca error al no darle un valor al vector  le coloque el valor de la variable que use para ingresar los datos eh igual me sale un error

Comment: ya lo resolví me faltaba utilizar un puntero muchas gracias por la ayuda